# Determining the CDF of $W = X - Y$ when $f(x,y) = 2e^{-x^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

I just want someone to check that my proceedings are correct.

So I'm given that $f(x,y) = 2e^{-x^2}$ when $0 \leq y \leq x$, $0 \leq x < \infty$. And I'm trying to find the Cumulative Distribution of $W = X - Y$.

Here's what I've done so far:

$w = x -y \geq x - x = 0$ so $w \geq 0$. So $F_W(w) = 0$ for $w < 0$.

So for when $w \geq 0$ we know that $x = w+y \geq w$ so we do as follows:
$$
\int_{w}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{w-x} 2e^{-x^2}dy \right) dx
$$

After that, we just do the double integration.
Is this correct? Can you spot a mistake or give some tips?

Comment: Note that, for every $w>0$, $$P(W<w)=P(X<Y+w)=\int_0^\infty\int_y^{y+w}2e^{-x^2}dxdy=\int_0^\infty2e^{-x^2}\int_{(x-w)^+}^xdydx$$ hence the CDF is $$F_W(w)=\int_0^\infty2e^{-x^2}\min\{w,x\}dx=\int_0^w2xe^{-x^2}dx+w\int_w^\infty2e^{-x^2}dx$$ that is, $$F_W(w)=1-e^{-w^2}+w\int_w^\infty2e^{-x^2}dx$$ More simply, the PDF is $$f_W(w)=\int_w^\infty2e^{-x^2}dx$$

Answer (score 0):

The integration range is $\{(x,y):~ 0\leqslant x-y\leqslant w~,~ 0\leqslant y\leqslant x~\}$.

Which can be rearranged to: $\{(x,y):~ 0\leqslant x ~,~ x-w\leqslant y\leqslant x~\}$

That is: the support for $X$, and for $Y$ given $X$.

Thus giving the double integral:

$$\mathsf P(X-Y\leq w) = \int_0^\infty\int_{x-w}^x f(x,y)\operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$